# React bind changes of the childrens

Tags: socket.io, reactjs

I'm trying to bind my child views (Table classes) to socket event.

```
var APP = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'APP',

    getInitialState(){

        return {
            tables: [],
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function componentWillMount() {

        this.socket = io('www.example.com');
        this.socket.on('tables', this.tables);
        // this.socket.on('table', this.table); ????

    },
    emit: function(eventName, payload){

        this.socket.emit(eventName, payload);
    },
    tables(serverState){

        this.setState({ tables: serverState });
    },
    render: function render() {

        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            React.createElement(Tables, { tables: this.state.tables, emit: this.emit })
        );
    }

});
```

So here I've creating for each item in array Table class. When I receive socket from tables my Tables are rendered. When I receive table socket with existing id in array but with different status, how can render it?

```
var Tables = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'Tables',

  render: function render() {

      return React.createElement("aside", null,

          React.createElement("ul", { className: "class" },
          this.props.tables.map(function (table, i) {

            return React.createElement( Table , { key: i, table: table, emit: this.props.emit });

          }, this)
        )
      );
    }
});
```

But how can I bind changes only for one item in array? Only for one Table class? When I receive socket to table, what I have to do to rerender this view, not entire Tables?

```
var Table    = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'Table',

  handleClick: function(i) {

    console.log(this.props.table);
  },
  render: function render() {

    return React.createElement("li", {

      onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this, this.key) },

      React.createElement("span", { className: "clscc" + this.props.table.status })

    );
  }
});
```

I was working before in backbone, so changes of one item was bind to model... How can I do it in react way? Thanks for any help